# What are nontrivial factors of $F_{F_n}$ upto $n=137$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $F_n$ denote the $n$ th Fibonacci number and define $f(n):=F_{F_n}$

- $f(n)$ is prime for $n=4,5,7$
- If we have $n>4$ and $F_n$ is composite , then we only have to know a prime factor of $F_n$ , say $q$. Then we have $F_q\mid f(n)$

The next few primes $n$ (after $n=7$) for which $F_n$ is prime as well (so $f(n)$ has a chance to be prime at all) are $$11,13,17,23,29,43,47,83,131,137$$

The small prime factors are ("?" means that no prime factor is known) :

```
 11                                   1069
 13                                 139801
 17       11144839714262653068143078433637
 23                                      ?
 29                                      ?
 43                                      ?
 47                                      ?
 83                                      ?
131                                      ?
137                                      ?
```

$f(43)$ is already huge (more than $90$ million digits) , so it is almost surely composite. Who knows prime factors of the seven unknown cases ? Is the prime factor of $f(17)$ the smallest ?

$f(23)$ and $f(29)$ are known to be composite. $f(23)$ has probably no prime factor below $10^{20}$ and for the other cases , there is no prime factor below $2\cdot 10^8$.

Who knows prime factors for the open cases ?

Comment: $$3105709700033\mid F_{F_{29}}$$

Comment: $f(43)$, $f(47)$, $f(83)$, $f(131)$, and $f(137)$ have no prime factor below $10^{10}$.